# Implicit conversion IQueryable<IGrouping<string, T>> to type IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am having some trouble trying to make a cast or make the right conversion.
I have a query of type `IQueryable<T>` T been a class:

```
var query = (from x in query
             group x by US.FirstName into g
             select g).Distinct();
```

I receive this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Link.IGrouping<string,T>>` to `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>`.>>

What I want to perform in fact is to return unique values of a query.

Comment: Unique values in what sense? Just the unique first names? It would really help if you could give us some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Unique values in the sense that this query as stated without the Distinct() would return some duplicate data. Sample Data : Jon : Activated the application, jon : Closed the application, Jon : Open Again the application. What I want to do is just return one single action of Jon, not the whole bunch of Jon's actions for example.

Comment: @Francky Yes, but all of your example data is already unique as a whole.  They are not, however, unique in the context of firstname `Jon`.  Are you simply trying to get a list of all distinct names in this action list?  Which of the items in your example would you consider to be duplicate, and would expect to be removed using a `Distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vQuery = vQuery.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName)
         .Select(g => g.First());
```

but this will be rather arbitrary : you should do an `OrderBy` or an `OrderByDescending`

```
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.WhatEverYouWant).First())
```

found with "your" syntax

```
vQuery = (from US in vQuery
 group US by US.FirstName into g
 select g.First())
```

Comment: @Francky Hmmm, not used with the query syntax. Isn't this one better ?

Comment: The last one is right and seems to be working fine. Thanks for your support @Mike C, Jon Skeet and you Raphael. I think I'll love this stackoverflow.

Comment: @Francky well, it was the same as the first I gave, in fact, just a problem of brackets when you tried it : `g.First())` instead of `g).First()`

Answer (score 0):

When you perform grouping in LINQ you actually return a collection of `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>`.  You are trying to put this result back into the variable you've defined for your original query `vQuery`, which is of type `IQueryable<T>`.  You need to put the result of your  LINQ query into a separate variable that is of type `IGrouping<TKey, TValue>`:

```
var groupedValues = (from US in vQuery
                     group US by US.FirstName into uniqueFirstName
                     select uniqueFirstName).Distinct();
```

Comment: Mike C, the var type does half the trick and I tried it before. The thing is vQuery is already strongly type. It is used in a method like : private void Filter(BackgroundWorker bw, ref IQueryable<T> vQuery)  {}

Comment: I realize that `vQuery` is strongly typed, and technically `groupedValues` is strongly typed after this line executes.  Your problem is that `vQuery` and the result of your query are two different types, and cannot be swapped out interchangeably.